# check for duplicate data before insert

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

I'm creating a java swing program where users can create a record, but I want to be able to check for duplicates before allowing the users to create the record. Here's my code:

```
public boolean createAssignRequest(AssignmentRequests assignReq) {

    int id = assignReq.getReqId();
    String dutyName = assignReq.getDutyName();
    String volNric = assignReq.getVolNric();

    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    String dbQuery = "";

    db.getConnection();

    dbQuery = "INSERT into assignrequests (dutyName, volNric)"
            + " VALUES ('" + dutyName + "','" + volNric + "')";

    if (db.updateRequest(dbQuery) == 1) {
        success = true;
    }
    db.terminate();

    return success;

}
```

whereby users cannot create the record if a row with the same dutyName and volNric already exists. 
If I were to execute this line of sql statement

```
ALTER TABLE `assignrequests` ADD UNIQUE `uniqueindex`(`dutyName`, `volNric`);
```

would I implement it in mySQL (just one time even if i truncate my data) or in my program codes? (I'm using eclipse)
I'm also using a three-tier architecture :-)
Finally, how would I implement the code to show a JOptionPane if a duplicate record is already detected? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If any use already has record then he mot able to create records am I right?

Comment: @Hardik yeah! if the user has already created a particular record with a particular dutyname and volnric he can't do the same creation again!

Comment: Please check the answer you just need to catch the exception and write your error

Answer (score 2):

If you want `DutyName` and `volNric` to have unique values, then do so with a unique constraint/index:

```
create index idx_assignrequests_dutyname_volnric on assignrequests(dutyname, volnric);
```

Then, when you do the `insert`, you can let it fail.  Or, you can just ignore it using `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT into assignrequests(reqId, dutyName, volNric)"
    VALUES ('" + id + "','" + dutyName + "','" + volNric + "')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dutyName = VALUES(dutyName);
```

The column being updated is being set to itself -- so the operation doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely agree with the @hd1 answer you need to apply this condition for the query after creating the unique constraint.

You need to create unique constraint first to any of your column that you need as a unique column.

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This is duplicate Value ')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a choice for

- INSERT IGNORE ("IF NOT EXISTS")
- INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

In the CREATE TABLE there must be a constraint, unique key on the unique fields. Otherwise ALTER TABLE.

I leave it to you to make a choice and inspect the mysql reference documentation.

I assume `reqId` is an AUTOINCREMENT primary key.

In the INSERT leave it out, to be generated by the database, in order to not have concurrency problems, of two people at the same time getting a new reqId.

Furthermore use PreparedStatement; this is really almost obligatory, as it escapes apostrophe and backslashes; prevents SQL injection, looks better.

```
try (PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT IGNORE INTO assignrequests (dutyName, volNric) VALUES(?, ?)")) {
    stm.setString(1, dutyName);
    stm.setString(2, volNric);
    int updateCount = stm.executeUpdate();
    if (updateCount != 0) {
        try (ResultSet genKeys = stm.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (genKeys.next()) { // At most 1 record inserted
                // Normally only one key generated per record.
                int reqId = genKeys.getInt(0);
                ...
            }
        } // Close result set.
    }
} // Closes stm
```