# before insert into mysql database how we will check is there any duplicate value using java

Tags: java, mysql-workbench

I have a registration table. I want to insert data into that table, but before insertion I want to check if any data like email already exists. It will insert, if the data is not same then it will insert.

Comment: Please refer this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245310/check-for-duplicate-data-before-insert

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it would be enough to configure a UNIQUE restriction in those columns you don't want to be duplicated. Then you only have to deal with the exception thrown if any unique field already exists in the table.

Another option (worse in performance) may be to execute an SQL statement to ensure your data is unique, but I recommend you the first option for its simplicity and performance.

Answer (score 0):

**UNIQUE KEY will help you:**

Write your query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Registration
(
 email varchar(255) UNIQUE,
   // comment: other fields here
)
```

Catch exception in your java code:

```
try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into registration(email,....) values (?,....)");

        //other fields go here

        ps.setString(1, email);
        ps.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```