# Checking before insert

Tags: java, mysql, sql, duplicates

I would like to check my first field and the second (CodeA, TitreA) and stop duplicates.

I don't know what to do.

```
public boolean insertAlbum (Album alb)
  {
    boolean ok = ConnexionMySQL.getInstance().actionQuery(
      "Insert into album (CodeA, TitreA, SortieA, IdentC) values ('" +
      alb.getCodeA() + "','" + 
      alb.getTitreA() + "'," +
      alb.getSortieASQL() + "," + 
      alb.getChanteurAlb().getIdentC() + ")");
    return ok;
  }
```

Comment: Make `CodeA` and `TitreA` be composite unique constraint in the database (this type of logic is generally a requirement of the database not the application)

Comment: Also, make use of `PreparedStatement` before someone screws your database. See [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer at school we do not see "Prepared Statement"
How to do with my request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check for duplicate data before insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245310/check-for-duplicate-data-before-insert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database table should enforce uniqueness of that column combination. Add this to your database:

```
alter table album add constraint unique_code_titre unique (codea, titrea);
```

Then, if you try inserting the same combination, it will show you an error, and won't insert the new row.